# How do I use a common log4net reference in assemblies loaded at runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, logging, log4net, dynamic-binding

I have a single-threaded application that loads several assemblies at runtime using the following:

```
objDLL = Assembly.LoadFrom(strDLLs[i]);
```

I would like the assemblies loaded in this manner to use the same log4net.ILog reference as the rest of the assemblies do. But it appears the runtime loaded assemblies have a different reference altogether and need their own configuration. Does anyone know if a single log4net.ILog can be used across assemblies loaded at runtime using a .NET interface?

Here is the log4net.ILog creation and supporting code in the Program class:

```
   // Configure log4net using the .config file
   [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

   public static class Program
   {
      private static log4net.ILog m_Log = null;

      [STAThread]
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         try
         {
            m_Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(
               MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
         }

      }
   }
```

Comment: Why would you need them all to have the same ILog? You can have one ILog per class, and they all log to the root logger by default.

Answer (score 2):

If all your assemblies implement a common interface, then you could have a property or constructor parameter that allows you to pass your local instance of ILog to the dynamically loaded assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the same logger by specifying a literal logger name string, thus getting the same logger instance.

```
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("SomeLogger");
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer comes 4 years late, but I just encountered the same issue.  In my case, I discovered that the assembly that was being loaded (from a different folder than the calling assembly) was also loading its own instance of log4net.

I fixed the issue by deleting the log4net.dll file from the folder where the runtime assembly was being loaded.

Comment: OMG ! This one solved my problem where logging in dynamically loaded assemblies never worked whereas it was working fine when the assemblies where in reference in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Something about the runtime loaded class prevents the usual one ILog per class from working. I can get a valid ILog instance, but unlike all the other instances it appears not to be configured (all the Is**Enabled flags are set to false). Perhaps the "root" logger is not accessible to the classes loaded at runtime???

Answer (score 0):

I have a stupid solution. You can set the XmlConfiguration to the main log4net config file.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="<configpath>",Watch = true)]
```

It is not really beauty .. but it runs.